# Error: third arg must be a format string. 2 plots 1 graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a line graph over a bar graph. Here's my code:

```
def hridef_base(x):
    if x == 1:

        deltatlapentry = EntrySummary['Avg tLap'] - EntrySummary2['Avg tLap']
        deltatlapapex = ApexSummary['Avg tLap'] - ApexSummary2['Avg tLap']
        deltatlapexit = ExitSummary['Avg tLap'] - ExitSummary2['Avg tLap']

        index = (EntrySummary.index + 1)
        barwidth = 0.2

        plt.ylim(0.0, 65.0)
        plt.bar(index-barwidth, EntrySummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='r', yerr=EntrySummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Entry')
        plt.bar(index, ApexSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#4169E1', yerr=ApexSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Apex')
        plt.bar(index+barwidth, ExitSummary['Avg FRH'], barwidth, color='#32CD32', yerr=ExitSummary['FRH StDev'], ecolor='k', label='Exit')

        plt.plot(index-barwidth, deltatlapentry, barwidth, color='k', label='Entry')
        plt.plot(index, deltatlapapex, barwidth, color='k', label='Entry')
        plt.plot(index+barwidth, deltatlapexit, barwidth, color='k', label='Entry')

        plt.xlabel('Turn Number')
        plt.ylabel('Average FRideH')
        plt.title('Average FRideH for Baseline setup')
        plt.xticks(index)
        plt.legend()
        plt.figure()

    else:
        print "Baseline FRideH Not Selected"
```

The error that I'm receiving is this:

```
    ValueError: third arg must be a format string
```

I'd appreciate any help in the matter.

(I should note that at the end of the code is when I run the function and plt.show)

Comment: At  what line do you receive this error?

Comment: Ah sorry! the first plt.plot line. I'm assuming the other 2 plt.plots will also fail

Comment: 3rd argument must be a formatting  string, not a float (barwidth in your case) . See matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: why are you giving `plt.plot` a barwidth? just remove that and it should work fine

Comment: haha realised one of my mistakes... obviously a line graph doesn't have a barwidth!!! duh me!!!